# How to Generate AUTO INCREMENT Id in Erlang Mnesia

Tags: database, erlang, elixir, mnesia

I am trying to write records to mnesia, and I want to assign a unique Id to every record. Id needs to be auto incremented.

For instance i have a table with 3 columns - Id, Name, DOB.

Record 1 should have Id = 1, Name = Joe, DOB = 03-05-1994

Record 2 should have Id = 2, Name = Alice, DOB = 11-07-1991 and so on...

Please Help

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you have to keep track of the last id by hand.  You can create a `table_ids` table which keeps track of the last id used when inserting a record in a given table. The `table_ids` table can be used to separately track the last id used in all your different tables.

According to the mnesia docs, rather than doing the math yourself by reading the last id for a table from the `table_ids` table, then incrementing the last id, then writing the last id back to the `table_ids` table, instead you should simply call [mnesia:dirty_update_counter()](http://erlang.org/doc/man/mnesia.html#dirty_update_counter-3).  Here's an example:

```
-module(my).
-compile(export_all).
-include_lib("stdlib/include/qlc.hrl"). 

-record(person, {id, name, age}).
-record(table_id, {table_name, last_id}).

init() ->
    mnesia:create_schema([node()]),
    mnesia:start(),

    {atomic, ok} = mnesia:create_table(people, [ 
       {record_name, person},
       {attributes, record_info(fields, person)}
    ]),

    {atomic, ok} = mnesia:create_table(table_ids, [
       {record_name, table_id},
       {attributes, record_info(fields, table_id)}
    ]).

start_counter(TableName) ->
    Fun = fun() ->
                mnesia:write(table_ids, 
                  #table_id{table_name=TableName, last_id=0}, 
                  write
                )
          end,
    {atomic, ok} = mnesia:transaction(Fun).



insert(Name, Age) ->
    Index = mnesia:dirty_update_counter(table_ids, people, 1),
    Fun = fun() ->
                mnesia:write(people,
                    #person{id=Index, name=Name, age=Age},
                    write
                )
          end,
    {atomic, ok} = mnesia:transaction(Fun).

select_all() -> 
    {atomic, People} = mnesia:transaction(
         fun() ->
              qlc:eval(
                qlc:q([X || X <- mnesia:table(people)])
              )
         end
    ),
    People.
```

In iex:

```
~/erlang_programs/mnesia$ rm -rf Mnesia.nonode\@nohost/

~/erlang_programs/mnesia$ erl
Erlang/OTP 20 [erts-9.3] [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [ds:4:4:10] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]
Eshell V9.3  (abort with ^G)

1> c(my).                   
my.erl:2: Warning: export_all flag enabled - all functions will be exported
{ok,my}

2> my:init().               
{atomic,ok}

3> my:start_counter(people).
{atomic,ok}

4> my:insert("Joe", 22).    
{atomic,ok}

5> my:insert("Sue", 31).    
{atomic,ok}

6> my:select_all().         
[{person,1,"Joe",22},{person,2,"Sue",31}]

7> mnesia:stop().           
stopped

8> 
=INFO REPORT==== 9-Jan-2019::23:30:02 ===
    application: mnesia
    exited: stopped
    type: temporary

(Hit Return to get back to prompt)
8>
```